# Do comments occupy space in compiled C++ sketch? Arduino / NodeMCU

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, c++, nodemcu

I tend to leave old code around as comments until I am sure that my current version is stable.  Just the way I like working.  I am concerned that I may be unnecessarily bloating up my sketches.

Do comments occupy space in an Arduino IDE compiled C++ sketch for Arduino (Nano, Uno)?  Is it correct to suppose that the behavior would be the same for NodeMCU?

Comment: you can determine that by compiling two identical sketches, one of which has a huge amount of comments

Comment: Not related to your question but... you should learn to use version control, and use comments for... commenting the code!

Comment: Unrelated, unhelpful, unasked for and... mistaken.  One is often wrong when guessing with little or no information to base one's assumptions upon.  I am talking about in between versions, as is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: What's unhelpful, unasked for and mistaken? Edgar's comment about source control is a **very** good suggestion. (Keeping your old code in the file as comments is superfluous if you use version control.)

Answer (score 3):

The C/C++ processor (which processes only the #define & #include statements) is the first stage of the compilation process. It runs before the compiler does and strips out everything that isn't code. The compiler will never see your comments.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Comments don’t take up any space.